Imagemagick not found moviepy
I always get this error on Moviepy:
convert: unable to read font `Courier' @ warning/annotate.c/RenderType/1024.
convert: delegate library support not built-in 'Courier' (Freetype) @ warning/annotate.c/RenderFreetype/2112.
convert: no decode delegate for this image format `' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/746.
convert: no images defined `PNG32:/tmp/tmpaopide7d.png' @ error/deprecate.c/ConvertImageCommand/3368.

I tried setting the policy and installing IM 6.

Your system does not appear to have the Courier font on it.
